# Check if RSS feed has an update?

Tags: php, rss

I am getting an RSS feed on my site. How can I check if the RSS files have changed and then update them. I'm doing this manually through PHP.

basically i have 12 news stories on my site, but they change based on the RSS feed. I can click "refresh" every once in a while, but is there a smarter way to do it?

Comment: So you aren't reading the RSS when your page loads?

Comment: Maybe it's time to consider putting some Ajax logic on your page? It could "refresh" the displayed RSS feeds "asynchronously" regularly, without having to refresh the page manually.

Comment: true that - Also, I realized you can get the RSS_Title($string) store the titles in an array, and check the titles before you load and parse the feed URLs

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, but with creating files every 6 hours. I have put script into the cron job: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

In my case cron looks like this:
0 */6 * * * php /path/to/my/script.php